# Google sheets: publish some but not all worksheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet which compiles scheduling info for an event. The file has five worksheets. There are two worksheets which I want to publish to the web; the other three are for my use and to drive calculations.

I can see how to publish the entire file, and how to publish an individual worksheet. However, I cannot figure out how to publish say, sheet1 and sheet2 to a single document.

As a short-term workaround I have tried the following, which works after a fashion but I'm not a fan:

- Create a new file with two sheets
- Sheet1 uses an importrange call to grab the data from the original sheet1
- Sheet2 uses an importrange call to grab the data from the original sheet2
- I then publish the entirety of the new document

The finished product must be in Google Apps; that is a requirement I cannot dodge.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is that after publishing the spreadsheet, copy the link, then through "Published content & settings" remove the check next to "entire document" and select the ones you want to share.
The details in the upper part of the window will disappear including the link, and the publish button will be green again "pressable".
Your copied link is still active, you can still use it, and only the selected sheets will be seen on the web. It is also modifiable; if you checked different sheets, web share will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

You can hide the sheets that you don't want to publish, and then publish the entire document:

[image]

Published sheet:

[image]

### Solution 2:

You can publish selected sheets using the **Published Content & Settings** options on the **Publish to the Web** dialog box. In the dropdown menu you can select which sheets to include:

[image]

The published spreadsheet would look like this:

[image]

Note: It seems that the web page may not display all the selected sheets, only the first sheet. You can file a feature/bug request here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en

Comment: Thank you! I tried that, but for some reason I do not see the tab selectors in the published view; instead I only see the first sheet. Tried it in Firefox and Chrome; same result.

Comment: Are some of your sheets hidden? Please unhide all sheets first before publishing. Also, you should click the ````Start Publishing```` white button instead of the ````Publish```` green button to publish the selected unhidden sheets.

Comment: Just tried it again, and I'm still not seeing those selector tabs

Comment: Do you have a sample of the sheet that you are working on so I can check?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zmG4ZTOI78nWwIuJb-49AVm0bzLxQh12dNPBVpIgfA0/edit

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting that I can replicate the problem on the sample sheet, and it seems like a bug on the Sheets part. Anyway, a workaround for this is that you can hide the sheets you don't want to publish and then publish the entire document. That would publish only the unhidden sheets.

Comment: Same problem here: cannot publish selected tabs to the Web. Either all or one tab is published. The settings work against each other.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ibkhayyat:

You can append ?gid=*sheet code number* to the original entire-document link to set the landing sheet.

And, if you didn't copy that original entire-document link while it was there, instead of redoing everything, you can just use any of the links to individual sheets. Just delete &single=true from the end of the link address. You can also delete ?gid=*sheet code number* to get back to the original link, but you can also leave it to set the landing sheet with the respective sheet code number.